# Is there a way to set subscription to a UWP Store App fully featured, without Add-Ons and with unlimited trial?

Tags: uwp

I would like to publish a UWP app on the Microsoft Store with the following configuration.

-App is listed as Free+ with unlimited trial

-User downloads the app without purchasing and can use it forever, with all features

-A reminder will popup at each launch of the app to inform the user that this app has a trial unlimited in time but that he could purchase it for a few pennies by clicking a button. By doing so there will be a subscription recurrent billing (one year) for which he can opt out at anytime

Essentially, I am trying to mimic the donation subscription model, but with a fixed price, circa 1 dollar.

I see on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app) that there is a subscription options, great, but it requires me to create an add-on. I do not understand why those two are linked? Can't I create a subscription without an add-on, since my app comes as fully featured from the start?

Any help on how to achieve the above bullets, and clarification if possible is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***>App is listed as Free+ with unlimited trial***

This is possible because you could choose Unlimited for the trial according to this document: [Free trail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability#free-trial)

***>User downloads the app without purchasing and can use it forever, with all features***

This is possible as well. When you find that he has a trial certificate, don't limit any features.

***>Can't I create a subscription without an add-on, since my app comes as fully featured from the start?***

You might misunderstand the relationship between Subscription and Add-ons. Subscription is a type of Add-on. In the document you post, you could see that the first step of creating a subscription is to create an add-on and choose Subscription for product type. It doesn't matter whether your app is fully featured or not.

Currently, subscriptions are available for in-app purchases of digital products only, not for the app itself. So you can't create subscriptions that directly to the app. Please create add-on subscriptions instead.

Comment: thank you for your time. Indeed I believe I misunderstand the model. I will create add-on subscription, although the user will have all functionality already. So far I have a base price of 1 dollar, but I got stuck in the logic, hence my post. I think this does not reflect what I intend to do: Do you agree that, in the scenario above, I should set the Base Price to Free? And the add-on will be priced for a dollar or so? Thanks

Comment: Another question: Is there a sample somewhere on the subscription add-on, or is it essentially the same as any add-on, such as in the Store Sample on github?

Comment: @Octopus What I can only say is that technically, it is possible to make the app always free trial and create subscriptions with a price. It depends on you whether to implement it or not. And for the other question- the codes sample are all posted in the document :[Code examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app#code-examples). I remember the sample in Github doesn't contain the subscription part.